# Excel hyperlink to specific tab (in another file)

Tags: excel, function, hyperlink

I was searching the web far and wide, with no good answer yet...

My excel worksheet blocked for "easy" hyperlink. I can't access the wizard.
I've opened a new file and figured that by the wizard I can go to specific tab with

```
filename.xlsx#TabName!A1
```

this should redirect me to tab "TabName" to square A1 within filename.xlsx.

I've managed to get to the file I want using

```
=HYPERLINK("[\\server\path\to\file\file.xlsx]", "Link text")
```

I've tried to get the code i've managed to discover:

```
=HYPERLINK("[\\server\path\to\file\file.xlsx]#TabName!A1", "Link text")
```

but no success.

anyone, can help? it redirects me to the file, but not to the tab I need.

thank you all in advace,
Ofek.

Comment: Just to check, when you put in TabName you are definitely putting quotations marks around it. For example #'Sheet 1'!A1 ?

Comment: Tried with and without. #TabName!A1 or #'TabName!A1' or #'TabName'!A1 or '#TabName!A1'.  Tried it all.

Comment: Can't seem to replicate it, unfortunately! Only two things I can think of off the top of my head are: 1. Make sure there is definitely a cell named A1, and that the sheet definitely has the right name (although I'm sure you've scanned over the name a million times!) 2. Make sure there isn't any VBA code that makes the file activate a particular tab when opening.

Comment: About the name - I've checked it. yes. about VBA - each time it opens in within the last tab i've been in when saved the file.

Comment: Is the tab you are trying to open specifically called "TabName" or is that a variable that will change the sheet that you want to open on? It may be worth updating your question with your full code to understand the wider issue.

Comment: The tab called TabName. No variables, just direct permanent hyperlink. there's no code. only excel functions.

Comment: Have you ever thought about using the Microsoft help offered with many examples on their website: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f BTW, there are no `#` in any of those examples.

Comment: Thank you Ralph, I actually did. Guess what? not helpful. at all. the # is from microsoft excel itself. I've explained in the main topic that using the wizard I've been given this "filename.xlsx#TabName!A1" example.